# Require JS still not loading shim content in order

Tags: javascript, requirejs, shim

I maybe doing something obviously wrong here, this is the code i have and i keep getting an error saying **_Packery is undefined** and i presume that is because it is loading before jQuery.

I have looked at the docs but i couldn't see why it isn't working correctly.

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: "ts="+new Date().getTime(), // disable caching - remove in production
    paths: {
        jquery: [
            "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min",
            "libs/jquery-191"
        ],
        packery: [
            "plugins/packery"
        ]
    },
    shim: {
        'packery': ['jquery']
    }
});


require(['jquery', 'packery'], function($) {

    var container = $('#container');
    container.packery({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        gutter: 10
    });

});
```

Any help that allows me to understand what i have done wrong would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that I have tried this same config setup with masonry and it works fine, so i don't know if this is just an issue with packery at the moment or just something else. Masonry is a suitable alternative for my needs

Answer (score 0):

I think u should define a shim like this:

```
 shim: {
        'packery': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
        }, ...
```

Then try to export packery like so...

```
require(['jquery', 'packery'], function($, packery) {

    var container = $('#container');
    container.packery({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        gutter: 10
    });

});
```

From official documentation: **jQuery is not required to use Packery. But if you do enjoy jQuery, Packery works with it as a jQuery plugin.**

Comment: thanks, i did try that from the require JS docs, but had no luck either

Comment: I think this may now be an issues with packery. I have just tried with masonry and it works fine.
To note i did also try doing your edit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Packery currently does not support AMD / Require JS. See https://github.com/metafizzy/packery/issues/20  However, this issue is in development and will be resolved in the future.

Comment: Isn't the point of shims to handle libraries that don't implement AMD?